# Update query using python odbc cursor - Not working

Tags: python, pyodbc, pypyodbc

I have this query executed with the following snippet:

```
cursor2.execute("UPDATE datatable SET data1 = ?, data2 = ?, data3 = ? WHERE id = ?",[d1,d2,d3,i])
print("affected rows = {}".format(cursor2.rowcount))
```

Affected rows returns 1 but row in database was not updated.

Printing the `d1,d2,d3` is fine only the update in the database doesn't work.

Is there something wrong with the function?

Additional:

I tried this way:

```
sql_update_query = """UPDATE datatable SET data1 = %s, data2 = %s, data3 = %s WHERE id = %s"""
inputData = (d1,d2,d3,i)
cursor2.execute(sql_update_query, inputData)
```

But it retuns this error:

```
('HY000', 'The SQL contains 0 parameter markers, but 4 parameters were supplied')
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: You may need to issue a `commit` somewhere. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20199569/pyodbc-insert-into-sql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are missing `.commit()`

**Ex:**

```
cursor2.execute("UPDATE datatable SET data1 = ?, data2 = ?, data3 = ? WHERE id = ?",(d1,d2,d3,i))
cursor2.commit()
```