# Effectively load data into Azure Synapse Database

Tags: etl, azure-synapse, data-transfer

I am trying to read data from MySQL database and load it in bulks to Azure Synapse database using `pyodbc` library and OBDC 18 driver, I've managed to do so but the loading into the Synapse DB step takes a lot of time and I suspect that it is very inefficient, here is my attempt:

```
import mysql.connector
import pyodbc

def _connect_mysql(host_p, port_p, username_p, password_p):
    try:
        db = mysql.connector.connect(host=host_p, port=port_p, user=username_p, passwd=password_p, connection_timeout=1,
                                     auth_plugin='mysql_native_password')
        return db
    except Exception as e:
        print("Couldn't connect to mysql db. Error: %s" % (str(e)))
        exit()


bulk_size = 5000

mysql_host = "127.0.0.1"
mysql_port = 3306
mysql_username = 'root'
mysql_password = 'password'

con_mysql_db = _connect_mysql(mysql_host, mysql_port, mysql_username, mysql_password)
crsr_mysql_db = con_mysql_db.cursor()


crsr_mysql_db.execute('SELECT ID, VALUE, TIME FROM table.data;')

bulk_count = 0
with pyodbc.connect(
        'DRIVER={ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server};SERVER=tcp:' + server + ';PORT=' + str(
            port) + ';DATABASE=' + database + ';UID=' + username + ';PWD=' + password) as crsr_dwh_db:
    crsr_dwh_db.autocommit = True
    with crsr_dwh_db.cursor() as crsr_dwh_db_crsr:
        crsr_dwh_db_crsr.fast_executemany = True
        while True:
            bulk_rows = crsr_internal_db.fetchmany(int(bulk_size))
            if not bulk_rows:
                break
            bulk_count += 1
            print(f"Bulk number: {bulk_count}")
            crsr_dwh_db_crsr.executemany("insert into synapse_table.data(ID, VALUE, TIME) values (?, ?, ?)", bulk_rows)
```

As mentioned above, this code does work but it takes approximately 40 seconds just to load 1000 rows, what am I doing wrong?  what is the more efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to use the [Copy Data Tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-data-tool?tabs=data-factory) in Azure Data Factory/Synapse.

If you want to load using Python, run in a Synapse notebook and use Spark and the [Azure Synapse Dedicated SQL Pool Spark Connector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/spark/synapse-spark-sql-pool-import-export?tabs=scala%2Cscala1%2Cscala2%2Cscala3%2Cscala4%2Cscala5) instead of Pyodbc.

Sticking with Pyodbc, you can vastly improve your loading speed by sending the data in one JSON doc as a string and parsing and loading on the server.  See eg: [Update SQL Server database using stored procedure with table as paramater using PYODBC in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60745932/update-sql-server-database-using-stored-procedure-with-table-as-paramater-using/60746532#60746532)