# Bulk insert a buffer (stringIO) into SQL instead of a file path?

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, pandas

Is it possible to execute the bulk insert query in SQL Server with a buffer from Python (`df.to_csv(buffer)` where buffer is a Pandas dataframe) instead of a file path:

```
bulk insert #temp 
from 'file_path'        -- instead of a file_path, use buffer?
with (  

        fieldterminator = ',',
        rowterminator = '\n'

      );
```

The only way I can think of doing this is to have Python make a CSV file and store it locally, and then have SQL execute a bulk insert via the file path. However, is there a way to do this without storing it locally, and rather directly in Python/SQL Server?

Comment: no it has to be a file https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/bulk-insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: Send it as JSON. eg https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60745932/update-sql-server-database-using-stored-procedure-with-table-as-paramater-using/60746532#60746532

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft i think hwe will get the data faster by saving the csv and run a bulkinsert

Comment: At some size, probably.  But there's not a simple pure-python way to do that.  BULK INSERT requires the file to be visible to the SQL Server.  So you would need to use BCP or similar.