# Invalid column name when inserting into SQL Server

Tags: python, sql-server

I'm trying to run an insert from Python and I get an "incorrect column name" error, but it's displaying the value of the column I'm trying to extract from `irow` iteration.

Is there something I'm doing wrong here? I'm explicitly declaring column names below, I don't see how its confusing the values for the column names?

```
for irow in cursor.execute(storedProc):
    strObj = str(irow[0])
    strGrp = str(irow[1])
    print(strObj)
    print(strGrp)
    try:
        response = requests.get(irow[2], timeout=30, auth=('user', 'pw'))
        response.raise_for_status()
        # Code here will only run if the request is successful
        # print(response.json())
        strJson = "Stuff"
        #str(response.json())
        cursor.execute("INSERT INTO dbo.ApiResults ([Object], [Group], json) VALUES ('"+strObj+"','"+strGrp+"','"+strJson+"');")
```

Comment: If you parametrise your query properly, this issue will go away.

Comment: im new at python so feel free to educate me on how to do that

Comment: It depends what library you're using, @DougCoats. For example, pyodbc or pymssql.

Comment: pyodbc is what im currently using

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pyodbc insert into sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20199569/pyodbc-insert-into-sql)

Comment: Another suggestion: replace `cursor.execute` with `print` and look on output of your script. Copy-paste it into SQL Management Studio (or other client you're using), try to execute.

Comment: If you shared the actual database table schema, we could see what column names are valid for you to insert into

Comment: Though would tell the OP where the error is, @AlexYu , it won't fix the injection issue. The problem at its core is that they haven't parametrised.

Comment: It turns out that I was trying to reuse a connection that was already open. Seems kind of like a newb mistake but alas this is my first python project. I am working on using params to satisfy @Larnu though <3

Comment: @Larnu Of course. Looking for `print` is just a diagnostic measure

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9518148/pyodbc-how-to-perform-a-select-statement-using-a-variable-for-a-parameter